# How do I eliminate IP Spoof errors in my Belkin security log?

Tags: ip, spoofing

Verified it's not coming directly from a certain computer on the network. What could be wanting to spoof the WAN besides the probable reply of malware?
I can provide logs but not easy at the moment.

Simple time warner modem, belkin N150, couple clients

Comment: IP Spoofing is where the router sees a packet from an IP address on one interface that it believes should originate on the other interface.  Some more details would be needed, like what is the connectivity between the N150 and internet - is it in bridge mode?  Have you used a private address range internally (10.0.0.0, 192.168.0.0, 172.16.0.0)?